# Is it possible to get the number(count) of requests made on an Amazon s3 object?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Does AWS SDK for php supports number of get request's made on a particular object by their file name. Just need to find a unique count of the number of hits made on a particular object.  Basically amazon count's number of requests made on a bucket. Just curious to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 doesn't support this, so the PHP SDK won't either. Amazon doesn't count accesses for you.

You'd need to setup [S3 access logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LoggingHowTo.html) and use something to analyze those.

Comment: Can you provide the link to a documentation which says that it does not provide it. I am unable to find it.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam S3 wouldn't offer logging as an optional feature if it automatically logged everything.